# Creating a self install macro?

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-word, vba

Hello I create many macros for my co workers. The current method I have for distributing to another computer is going into the vba editor and importing.

I would really like to make a kind of "installer" for macros that would allow the user to install a new macro without having to go into the editor. I'm not sure this is even possible but any ideas are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: One approach is to make your macros add-ins. It has the drawback of sometimes requiring some tweaking of the code (e.g. explicit workbook references are sometimes required) but would have the advantage of making it as easy to install as the Analysis ToolPack. See http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just send them a workbook with new macros for them to use? I ask because then you can simply have a macro that copies the updated workbook.

Comment: What I setup at my job is a shared folder that contains our utilities. When we update the utilities, we overwrite them on the global share. Whenever someone goes to use a utility, it grabs the version that is saved on the shared drive. This way, everyone is typically using the most recent version. In cases where they're not, the "update" button would simply overwrite the local workbook with the global workbook. If that method won't work for you and you absolutely have to import/export, you can use the code here http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enable Microsoft Scripting Runtime library under references. (VBE -> Tools -> References. Check the box.)

Basically, you create a string that holds the code of the macro you want to install. Obviously, the string could be really long with many lines of code so you might need several string variables.

```
Dim toF As Workbook
Dim codeMod As CodeModule
Dim code As String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim name As String, file As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\folder\here")
name = nameOfFileHere
file = folder & "\" & name

Set toF = Workbooks.Open(file)
'modify ThisWorkbook  to place it elsewhere
Set codeMod = toF.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule

'erase everything if code already exists
If codeMod.CountOfLines > 0 Then
    codeMod.DeleteLines 1, codeMod.CountOfLines
End If

'dump in new code
code = _
"Private Sub Workbook_Open()" & vbNewLine & _
"   Dim user as String" & vbNewLine & _
"   Dim target as String" & vbNewLine & _
"   user = Application.UserName" & vbNewLine & _
"   target = """ & findUser & """" & vbNewLine & _
"   If user = target then" & vbNewLine & _
"   MsgBox ""I just dumped in some code.""" & vbNewLine & _
"   End if" & vbNewLine & _
"End Sub" & vbNewLine

With codeMod
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, code
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Interesting code. I can foresee a couple of issues: 1) what about userforms? 2) Isn't there some sort of "Trust access to the VBA project" setting that would have to be manually set?

Comment: Good point on the userform. I have another macro that can alter the trust access setting somewhere...

Comment: Even if you have to modify a security setting by hand, your approach still seems like less work then having to go to the VBE and importing stuff manually.

Comment: Right but as you implied, it's best for short/simple macros. Also, code for the setting change via http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2012/02/29/vba-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros.aspx