# Distribute updated Excel VBA code to Multiple End-Users

Tags: vba, excel

I've created an Excel 2010 workbook with a number of sheets.  VBA code that performs various data manipulations is in a couple of modules, and also attached to a couple of forms.  The workbook is being distributed to a couple dozen people in different departments to use.  They will be populating their workbook with their own department-specific data.

If I need to distribute an update to the code (either a bug fix or some new function), how can that be done?  I don't want the users to have to reenter or copy/paste all their data into the 'new' workbook - I'm essentially looking for a method to update the VBA Project that's inside their existing workbook.

Comment: Ship the code as a stand-alone VBA project in a centrally located (ie on a LAN) workbook that the data workbooks link to on startup. Or, convert to Visual Studio Tools for Office and use Click-Once deployment

Comment: Will it be only the VBA code which changes, or will the structure of the workbook also change (sheet names, column headers, named ranges etc etc) ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392299/creating-a-self-install-macro/31393407#31393407) doesn't work with forms but it's food for thought.

Comment: Tim - only the VBA code will change.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an additional helper workbook `Help.xlsm`, that has its file attributes set to read-only.

Move all the `vba` code, that you might need to change in the future, into `Help.xlsm`

The file that you distribute then needs a reference adding to `Help.xlsm`

Now in the future changes can be made to `Help.xlsm` and they should appear in the client's files.

Above assumes all your customers are on the same network so that you can store `Help.xlsm` somewhere that is accessible to all their files.

This article explains it better than me:
http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused on how to implement this. I too came upon the link you shared and it is exactly what I need. I just can't figure out how to incorporate it in my .xlam (add-in) file. Could you have a look at my existing question on this same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583430/how-would-i-implement-this-code-into-my-excel-add-in)? It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder I don't use an xlam - I just use an xlsm with it's attribute set to read-only: this means several workbooks can have a reference to it.

Comment: That's a shame. I'm using an xlam instead in order to protect my code. I just can't figure out how to apply this though.

Comment: Password protect and still allow users to access the vbe. That's why I needed to make it an add-in

Comment: Are all your users using your addin? If so you need to make sure when they use the addin they install it from a network drive and that they choose NOT to save a copy locally when installing

Comment: Already have that part taken care of with a vbscript that automates the install and activation of the add-in

Comment: @whytheq how does this approach work with updating code on the worksheet level?

Comment: @Jose no need to change code in each sheet but each book can plug into this addin and the code in the addin can be changed

Answer (score 1):

You would need to export the modules and forms and manually import them into the existing workbooks.  I used to have to do this for some projects i worked on.

Alternatively you would need to write some helper code to import the old data into a newly published workbook, but this depends on how the data is organised of course.  Again this is another approach I took for a different project.

You can also do this procedurally.  Ive used this for small patches.
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx