# Combining two .xlsx worksheets in separate xlsx files into a single worksheet in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript, merge, excel.application

I need to accomplish this with vbscript (not vba).  I cannot find any examples of how to do this.  I've got vbs that does all of the major processing to the Excel files I need, but the last piece I need is simply to merge both worksheets which reside in 2 separate .xlsx files into a single worksheet into a new workbook.

I've found examples of merging 2 files into a single wb with separate sheets using vba, but I need them on the same sheet and via vbscript.  It would basically be like a union of the two sheets.  They both contain the same number of columns (6 columns) with the same type of data.  Basically need to copy the headers from either of the spreadsheets and paste into new workbook/worksheet, then copy all of the data from each into the new workbook/sheets below the headers.  Hope this makes sense.  Any help is appreciated.

I'm semi close with this, this brings the two data sheets into the same NEW workbook called "merged", but need it to merge the sheets into one.

```
    Set objExcel = WScript.CreateObject ("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = false

strFileName = "c:\excel\merged.xlsx"

 Set objWbA = objExcel.WorkBooks.open("c:\excel\wb1.xlsx")
 Set objWbB = objExcel.WorkBooks.open("c:\excel\wb2.xlsx")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

 objwba.worksheets(1).copy _
 objWorkbook.worksheets(1)
 objwbb.worksheets(1).copy _
 objWorkbook.worksheets(2)

objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
objWorkbook.close

objWbA.Close True
objWbB.Close True

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

==========================

Here is a solution I came up with (went with a CSV output):

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel
Dim strFilename
Dim objWbA
Dim objWbB
Dim Lastrow
Dim Lastrow1
Dim objWorkbook
Dim objSheeta
Dim objSheetb

Set objExcel = WScript.CreateObject ("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = false
objExcel.displayalerts = false

strFileName = "c:\excel\merged.csv"

 Set objWbA = objExcel.WorkBooks.open("c:\excel\wb1.xlsx")

 Set objSheeta = objWbA.Sheets("wb1")

 Set objWbB = objExcel.WorkBooks.open("c:\excel\wb2.xlsx")

 Set objSheetb = objWbB.Sheets("wb2")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

Const xlUp = -4162
Const xlPasteValues = -4163
Const xlPasteFormats = -4122
Const xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats = 12

with objSheeta
Lastrow = .Cells(objSheeta.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      .Range("B1:F" & Lastrow).Copy
end with

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

with objSheetb
Lastrow1 = .Cells(objSheetb.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
      .Range("B2:F" & Lastrow1).Copy
end with

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Lastrow1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'===================================

objExcel.CutCopyMode = False
objExcel.ScreenUpdating = True

objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName), 6
objWorkbook.close True

objWbA.Close True
objWbB.Close True

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: You have been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary to post a bunch of code that wasn't close.  I described the effort in the OP.  Just looking for some guidance.  I've been researching this and trying many different things for 2 days now.  I post here as a last resort.  Lately, my posts have been generating responses like yours which forces me to find a less desirable solution on my own or in another forum.  Not very helpful.  However, I posted code above that is somewhat in the ball park.  But, again, lacking a lot.

Comment: `Lately, my posts have been generating responses like yours` that should be an indication for some reflection on your part? `didn't think it was necessary to post a bunch of code that wasn't close` So you're simply asking SO to code for you which is not what SO is about. Try coding something then come back and ask a better question.

Comment: Nah, you've got me wrong.  I don't expect anyone to code for me.  I would think my prior posts would speak to that.  Not sure where the hostility is coming from.  This is simply a case where I can't generate enough information on my own so I'm asking SO to help me to translate my question into something more understandable and or point me in a direction.  My own resources are tapped.  Happy to try to further clarify my request if it helps others to get what I'm trying to do.  Hey, findwindow, I still love you.

Comment: Until you post code that is actually close to what you want to achieve, you **are** asking others to code for you. Why do I engage trolls XD Good night.

Comment: I'm a troll now?  How about assuming I'm not looking for someone to code for me and just provide useful info.  Like this post, for example, someone asks a question and get's helpful responses and by the way -  I see you provided code here without prompting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392299/creating-a-self-install-macro/31393407#31393407.  Maybe you shouldn't assume this is what everyone wants.  If you don't have any suggestions, no worries, but no need to hijack the thread to criticize.  I'm here to learn, everyone, not to create work for findwindow.  This is silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform a [Worksheet.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx) and neglect to supply a destination, the worksheet will be copied to a new workbook which holds the [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx). This may be the best way to start off a new workbook.

```
Set objExcel = WScript.CreateObject ("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False    'True for testing

strFileName = "c:\tmp\merged"   '<~~ no file extension, FileType:=51 (xlOpenXMLWorkbook) will do that

 Set objWbA = objExcel.WorkBooks.open("c:\tmp\wb1.xlsx")
 Set objWbB = objExcel.WorkBooks.open("c:\tmp\wb2.xlsx")
 rws = objWbA.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count   '<~~ 65536 or 1048576 (need this below)

 objWbA.Worksheets(1).Copy   '<~~ copy to a new workbook with one worksheet
 objWbB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy _
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rws, 1).End(-4162).Offset(1,0)   '-4162 is xlUp

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFileName, 51  '<~~ 51 is FileType:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False   '<~~ saved on the line immediately above

objWbA.Close False   'don't save if we didn't change anything
objWbB.Close False   'don't save if we didn't change anything

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

The [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) will supply the correct file extension if you provide the correct value from the [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) for the **FileType**. There is no need to save the originals as they received no changes.

Comment: Thank you, Jeeped.  To be honest, I had abandoned this thread and worked out a solution on my own, but this is admittedly more elegant than mine.  I also appreciate the line comments.  For the sake of showing others that I don't rely on provided code (since it seems I need to prove myself), I'll post my own solution in the OP for good measure.