# Delete Macro from a Workbook the Macro has just created

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with a macro I have created. I am creating multiple workbooks based on a selection made by the user. However, I want to remove the macro, and a worksheet from each file I have created. The code I have tried stops the code looping through the range as it seems maybe it is deleting the macro from the original file I am working from. Below is the code as it stands now which creates the workbooks as I want them fine ***but*** still with the worksheet containing a command button  used to trigger the macro ***and*** the macro still in them. I need each file saved without them and the original template file to be unaffected.

```
Sub Button3_Click()


    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim currentSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MyRange = Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 5) = MyCell.Value
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\Clinical Scorecard Template\test\" & MyCell.Value & ".xls"
        'here I want it to then delete the macro and a sheet called "Member"
   Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Please note, I have tried the .xlsx file type but that also stops the loop - even if I use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: [Interesting read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392299/creating-a-self-install-macro/31393407#31393407)

Comment: @findwindow: Thank for that - however it's almost the reverse of what I need - I need the Macro to be deleted - not installed!!

Comment: @findwindow
[even more interesting read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427373/deleting-database-connection-in-excel-vba-macro)