# deleting database connection in excel vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

So I have managed to use a template to create multiple excel files that are saved as a `.xlsx` file to ensure the macro is not saved as part of the newly created files. *However*, I now have the problem of the database connections that are refreshed within macro. If I delete these, the following files create will have the data from the original file created as the connection strings have been broken. It seems the way this process works is that the next file is created from the previous, not from the template - a kind-of bucket brigade approach. Now I know people are going to ask me what I have tried but it has taken a few weeks (of time snatched when I get a chance) to get to this point and I can get no further. Please guys, I have googled and tried the hell out of everything but it is beyond me. *Please* can you help? I have included in my code, the part that deletes the connections - but as I say, this is not the correct approach it seems.
Thank you

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range


Dim LR As Long

If Dir("P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir Path:="P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\"

End If

If Dir("P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir Path:="P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\"

End If

 LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


'this gets the values for workbook names
Set MyRange = Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Dim xConnect As Object

For Each MyCell In MyRange


  'this populates a cell with the name in the range that the workbook then references for refreshing an MS query
    Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 5) = MyCell.Value
    Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 6) = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 7) = MyCell.Offset(, 2).Value
    Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 8) = MyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
    Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 9) = MyCell.Offset(, 4).Value

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B7:D16").Interior.Color = RGB(251, 222, 5) 'light yellow
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B6:D6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' dark yellow

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E6:E6").Interior.Color = RGB(231, 25, 25) 'dark red
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E7:G16").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'light red

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B17:D17").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'dark green
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B18:D32").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'light green


        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E18:G32").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").PivotTables("PivotTable3").DataBodyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RowRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E17:G17").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96) 'dark blue
'       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview Score Card").Range("C1").Copy
'       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview Score Card").Range("C1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Members").Visible = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Front Sheet").Visible = False
         Worksheets("Graphs Red Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        Worksheets("Graphs Blue Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        Worksheets("Graphs Yellow Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        Worksheets("Graphs Green Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\" & "CNST - " & MyCell.Value & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\" & MyCell.Offset(, 5).Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
           Dim wkb As Workbook
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\" & "CNST - " & MyCell.Value & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".xlsx")
        Dim wkb2 As Workbook
        Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\" & MyCell.Offset(, 5).Value & ".xlsx")



  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next MyCell
       ' this deletes connections
    For Each xConnect In wkb.Connections
                If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
        Next xConnect
       For Each xConnect In wkb2.Connections
                If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
        Next xConnect


       ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that _for each cell_ In `MyRange` you are opening `wkb` and `wkb2`. That seems wrong. And you save the workbook after formatting each cell.

Comment: "_the next file is created from the previous, not from the template_" Yes, that is because you keep re-using your active workbook.

Comment: @Paul Hi Paul - thank you for clarifying why it does that - how would I make it revert to the template every time then?

Comment: You can do as follows: 1) move the macro and base data to a separate workbook, then 2) re-open the template workbook from the macro for every workbook you want to create.

Comment: @Paul I am just struggling with the logical order of what you are saying - could you possibly post the pseudo code/logic of how this would work?

Comment: As per your request, I posted it as an answer. I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will sove your problem. See also the comments to your question.

The subroutine `Button3_clieck()` is in the current workbook. That workbook also has the cells with information to create the other workbooks.

You have a separate workbook with the sheets that you use as a template (create it from your current workbook with the macro). It is opened in the while loop for each cell:

```
Set wkbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(filename:="MyTemplate.xlsm")
```

After you formatted the sheets, you save it under your names and then close it. You will open it again in the next iteration of the while loop.

After saving your two workbooks, you re-open them again to remove the connection. Then you close them.

Now you process the next cell.

The following (pseudo) code illustrates this. I couldn't check the code so there may be some errors.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim xConnect As Object
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemplate As Workbook     ' this is the opened template
    Dim wkbThis As Workbook         ' this is a reference to this workbook

    Dim basepath
    basepath = "P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\"

    If Dir(basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir Path:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\"
    End If

    If Dir(basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir Path:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\"
    End If

    Set wkbThis = ActiveWorkbook    ' to prevent any confusion, we use abolute workbook references
    LR = wkbThis.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'this gets the values for workbook names
    Set MyRange = wkbThis.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each MyCell In MyRange

        Set wkbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(filename:="MyTemplate.xlsm")   ' re-open the template for each cell

        'this populates a cell with the name in the range that the workbook then references for refreshing an MS query
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 5) = MyCell.Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 6) = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 7) = MyCell.Offset(, 2).Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 8) = MyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 9) = MyCell.Offset(, 4).Value

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wkbTemplate.RefreshAll


        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B7:D16").Interior.Color = RGB(251, 222, 5) 'light yellow
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B6:D6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' dark yellow

        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E6:E6").Interior.Color = RGB(231, 25, 25) 'dark red
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E7:G16").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'light red

        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B17:D17").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'dark green
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B18:D32").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'light green

        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E18:G32").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").PivotTables("PivotTable3").DataBodyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RowRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E17:G17").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96) 'dark blue
'       wkbTemplate.Sheets("Overview Score Card").Range("C1").Copy
'       wkbTemplate.Sheets("Overview Score Card").Range("C1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wkbTemplate.Saved = True
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Members").Visible = False
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Front Sheet").Visible = False
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Red Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Blue Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Yellow Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Green Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value

        wkbTemplate.SaveAs filename:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\" & "CNST - " & MyCell.Value & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wkbTemplate.SaveAs filename:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\" & MyCell.Offset(, 5).Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wkbTemplate.Close SaveChanges:=False

        ' this deletes connections
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\" & "CNST - " & MyCell.Value & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".xlsx")
        For Each xConnect In wkb.Connections
            If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
        Next xConnect
        wkb.Close

        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\" & MyCell.Offset(, 5).Value & ".xlsx")
        For Each xConnect In wkb.Connections
            If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
        Next xConnect
        wkb.Close

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next MyCell

    'ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you Sir -Brilliant  this works an absolute treat!  The only change I made was to where the code is to delete the connections below:

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button3_Click()

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim xConnect As Object
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemplate As Workbook     ' this is the opened template
    Dim wkbThis As Workbook         ' this is a reference to this workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim basepath
    basepath = "P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\02 Clinical Scorecards\"
    Dim TempPath
    TempPath = "P:\Informatics\S&L scorecards\01 Scorecard Template\01 Clinical\"

    If Dir(basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir Path:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\"
    End If

    If Dir(basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir Path:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\"
    End If

    Set wkbThis = ActiveWorkbook    ' to prevent any confusion, we use abolute workbook references
    LR = wkbThis.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'this gets the values for workbook names
    Set MyRange = wkbThis.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each MyCell In MyRange

        Set wkbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TempPath & "MyTemplate.xlsm")   ' re-open the template for each cell

        'this populates a cell with the name in the range that the workbook then references for refreshing an MS query
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 5) = MyCell.Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 6) = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 7) = MyCell.Offset(, 2).Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 8) = MyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Front Sheet").Cells(5, 9) = MyCell.Offset(, 4).Value

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wkbTemplate.RefreshAll


        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B7:D16").Interior.Color = RGB(251, 222, 5) 'light yellow
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B6:D6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' dark yellow

        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E6:E6").Interior.Color = RGB(231, 25, 25) 'dark red
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E7:G16").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'light red

        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B17:D17").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 102, 0) 'dark green
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("B18:D32").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'light green

        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E18:G32").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").PivotTables("PivotTable3").DataBodyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RowRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 88, 154) 'light blue
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Speciality Score Card").Range("E17:G17").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96) 'dark blue
'       wkbTemplate.Sheets("Overview Score Card").Range("C1").Copy
'       wkbTemplate.Sheets("Overview Score Card").Range("C1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wkbTemplate.Saved = True
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Members").Visible = False
        wkbTemplate.Sheets("Front Sheet").Visible = False
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Red Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Blue Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Yellow Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value
        wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Graphs Green Zone").PageSetup.CenterFooter = wkbTemplate.Worksheets("Overview Score Card").Range("A4:F4").Value

        ' this deletes connections
        For Each xConnect In wkbTemplate.Connections
            If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
        Next xConnect




        wkbTemplate.SaveAs Filename:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\" & "CNST - " & MyCell.Value & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wkbTemplate.SaveAs Filename:=basepath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\Trust Code Files\" & MyCell.Offset(, 5).Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wkbTemplate.Close SaveChanges:=False



        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next MyCell

    'ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that is a better place to remove the connections.