# How to add a macro to an Excel document?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I recently began working with macros and VBA for work however my knowledge is currently very limited so please bear with me. I recently wrote a macro to apply a simple standardized format to all excel documents I send out to others. The macro has been working when I apply the macro from inside of excel, however I also have some automated reports I send out using python and I would like to use this macro on these reports as well to format them prior to sending.

My question is essentially, how do I add a macro to an existing excel document, how do I then execute that macro from python, and then save the resulting excel document?

I do not have much experience in using VBA code or interacting with this using python so I am not too sure where to start so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Below is the Macro I am looking to use

```
Sub Delphi_macro()

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("a1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't help with the python part but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392299/creating-a-self-install-macro/31393407#31393407) may help with adding a macro to excel.

Comment: looks like you mainly have the answers.  I would recommend not sending out with the macro still in it (cleaner for people to use as well) unless it will be used again.  The other thing I would say is that this uses a lot of selections and active references.  it may be best for this use to move these to ranges and defined books/sheets (i.e. `Thisworkbook` if its the one with the macro in it).  also just as a note, i dont think that first `With Selection` is actually doing anything it seems to all be completely redone by the following `with selection` with no change of selection inbetween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your Macro to a Module, and then Export the Module. After exporting the module you can use this python code to add it/import it and run it.

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Add
wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Full Path\VBA_Exported_Macro.bin"
xl.Application.Run("Module1.Delphi_macro")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs('final_outfile.xlsx', FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2) # Macro disapears here
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
xl = None
```

In the code above this is creating a fresh Excel Workbook, adding the macro, running it and then Saves the file WITHOUT the macro. You can change that and instead open an existing workbook and save as Macro enabled excel to retain the macro.

Comment: If you've already got the Excel Application object and the target workbook, why not just do the operations that are contained within the macro? Slap an `xl.` in front of every object name in the macro and you're like 90% of the way there.

Comment: Sure, the macro is simple enough to just do the operations on the python code, but the question was how to add a Macro to a workbook using python, this answers that and may help him/her out later on how to import a more advanced macro.

Comment: @bjl042 glad it helped. If the answer works for you please dont forget to mark it as answered. It it doesnt please let me know which part and I will try to answer it.

Comment: @RicardoA I would like to know, what if I am manipulating a file from linux? let use say I want to add VBA code to excel file in my ubuntu

Comment: @collinsmarra the python code above uses the windows libraries to call for the Excel application and then it uses the built in functions to add the macro. I have never tried this in Linux but there are ways to use the windows libraries such as Wine and other similar methods. I am still not sure if that will work.

Comment: @RicardoA thanks for replying. I noticed it is actually not possible on linux